# Что за плагин hugo-plugin?

Tags: android

Что за плагин hugo-plugin? для чего он нужен? в дос читал, понял что это связанное с аннотаций...
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На страничке проекта написано что этот плагин необходим для сбора и вывода дебажной информации по методам. Для включения необходимо метод пометить аннотацией `DebugLog`. После чего в `LogCat` будут выводится входные параметры метода, время выполнения метода и то, что возвращает метод.

Объясню на примере кода из ReadMe плагина.
Пусть есть метод:

```
@DebugLog
public String getName(String first, String last) {
    SystemClock.sleep(15); // Don't ever really do this!
    return first + " " + last;
}
```

После чего, если в коде его вызвать так:

```
String fullName = getName("Petr", "Petrov");
```

То в результате в логе вы увидите строчки:

```
V/Example: ⇢ getName(first="Petr", last="Petrov")
V/Example: ⇠ getName [16ms] = "Jake Wharton"
```

Где первая строка отображает входные параметры, а вторая результат работы метода и время работы метода.

Вывод информации будет осуществляться только в `debug` версии приложения.